# CasperJS not triggering onchange events

Tags: javascript, events, casperjs

I'm writing a CasperJS script to automatically fill a web form and scrape the results.

One field is like:

`<input name="code" class="inputField" onchange="doA()" onkeypress="return doB(this,event)">`

My script:

`casper.then(function visit_details() {
    casper.sendKeys('input[name="code"]', 'foobar');
    //...some other actions
})`

I expected the script to trigger calls to doA (once, after the statement) and doB (6 times, for the 6 keys in 'foobar'). However, neither function is called even once. Of course, when I type 'foobar' into the field in the web browser, the functions are called as expected.

I'm taking screenshots of every step (before and after the contents of the step), and am logging all errors to stdout, as per [the provided instructions](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js). I even ran a remote debugger, with a `debugger;` instruction right before the sendKeys call, and breakpoints set on the event handlers. The breakpoints were never hit.

The use case is that I'm trying to automate the filling of a form. The form runs some validation code on these event handlers, and can only be submitted once the event handlers have run.

Comment: How do you know that nothing is happening? Have you taken a screenshot? Have you waited a little before taking the screenshot? Have you tried observing the requests with the available events in CasperJS? Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Ah yes, apologies, I should have been more explicit about how I've checked that they're not getting called. Thanks for so actively helping the community out @ArtjomB.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Have you registered to the events I mentioned in my previous comment?